# Trouble with remove_if (it stops removing after a few removals)

Tags: c++, algorithm, remove-if

The code below wants to take a string and output only lowercase letters from the English alphabet.

```
string simplifyString(string word)
{
    word.erase(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char letter){return !isalpha(letter);}));
    transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), tolower);
    return word;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.";
    cout << simplifyString(s) << endl;;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is: abcdefgh.f.g.h.

So the code works and then stops working. What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
word.erase(remove_if(...));
```

That's close but not quite right.  That only removes the *first* element set aside by `remove_if`.  You want to remove the entire range:

```
word.erase(remove_if(...), word.end());
```